# User drawing isn't showing on the canvas

Tags: android, drawing, paint

I have an XML layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <com.somedomain.drawings.DrawingSurface
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:id="@+id/drawingSurface" 
            android:background="@drawable/bg2"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:id="@+id/colorGreenBtn" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I'm trying to draw on the DrawingSurface, the drawing isn't showing. But the background image of the canvas is showing. And when I save it, the drawing is showing on the output.

When I removed the background image of the DrawingSurface and try to draw to it, it is showing.

I want to show the drawing when the user draws on the canvas with the background image. Any ideas? Thanks a lot for any help! :)

Update: Here's my drawing code

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas = null;

    while (_run){
        if(isDrawing == true){
            try{

                canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                if(mBitmap == null){
                    mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                }


                final Canvas c = new Canvas (mBitmap);

                c.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                canvas.drawColor(0x00000000);

                commandManager.executeAll(c,previewDoneHandler);
                previewPath.draw(c);

                canvas.drawBitmap (mBitmap, 0,  0,null);
            } finally {
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You probably need to include your code since something is probably wrong with your drawing code.

Comment: Thanks for your response @David Olsson, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things to try:

1) put the ImageView before the drawSurface in XML, and put the bg into the ImageView.

I know the surfaceView is different than other view, but you could try out.

2) Maybe you could draw the bg onto the canvas first the drawing thread started.
canvas.drawBitmap() could be the one you wanna use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Terence Lui, on your first suggestion, I'm unable to make a transparent canvas background. I searched but I can't find something like that or my google skills are failing. Do you have sample code for your second suggestion? Do you mean I have to combine the bg image and the user's drawing?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you mean by "a transparent canvas" is actually a transparent surfaceView. When I was working on surfaceView, it had to be at the top or bottom of its "window". So So If you have nothing on top of the surfaceView, you can set the z-order of the surfaceView to the top of its window. and doing something like this when init the surfaceView:

surface(){ getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); /...}

Comment: But if you dont wanna make the surfaceView transparent( I think you wont, because you want a bg surfaceView), so all you have to do is draw the bg yourself and init the canvas like so: canvas = new Canvas(yourbgImageBitmap); so everything would draw on top of htis bitmap. That's hell lot of easier.